# quiz not redirecting to final page using xmhttp issue

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have to learn this from Youtube, PHP quiz using AJAX. I want to display question number navigation on the sidebar when I click any question number that question should display And Suppose I answered question no 1 and click on next then the background color of question number navigation should be green. The problem is when I click on question number navigation I get that question but when I select the option and click on the next button it previous question displays where it was And don't worry about SQL injection I will use a prepared statement, this is only a rough script for learning purposes. I think responseText is not working.

[Please see this what I want to do Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Q7M.png)

`Question.php` page to where I display question

```
  <div class="col-12 question-Number question_navigation" >
 <?php 
$category=$_SESSION['exam_category'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions  WHERE category=? ORDER BY question_no=?  ASC";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$category,$question_no);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
$ROW= $row['question_no'];
for($i=$ROW; $i<=$ROW; $i++){
?>
 <p type='button' id="quest-number" class='next_QUESTION' class="display" data-id="<?php echo $i ?>" ><?php echo $i ?></p>
 <?php
 }
}
?>
 </div>
            <!--------------------------------------------------->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function load_total_que(){
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("total_que").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/load_total_que.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
        </script>
        <!--------------------------------------------------->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var questionno="1";
        load_questions(questionno);
        function load_questions(questionno){
        document.getElementById("current_que").innerHTML=questionno;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                if(xmlhttp.responseText == 1){
                window.location="result.php";    
                }else{
                document.getElementById("load_questions").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                load_total_que();
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/load_questions.php?questionno="+ questionno,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
        </script>
        <!--------------------------------------------------->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function load_previous(){
        if(questionno=="1"){
                load_questions(questionno);
            }else{
                questionno=eval(questionno)-1;
                load_questions(questionno);
            }
        }
        function load_next(){
            questionno=eval(questionno)+1;
            load_questions(questionno);
        }
        $(document).on('click', '.next_QUESTION', function(){  
            var questionno = $(this).data("id");  
            load_questions(questionno);  
        });
        </script>
        <!------------------------SAVE----ANSWER---------------------->
        <script>
        function radioclick(radiovalue, questionno){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/save_answer_in_session.php?questionno="+ questionno + "&value1=" + radiovalue, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null); 
        }
        </script>
```

This is the `Question_load.php` page

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

?>
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../../configure/config.php");

$question_no="";
$question="";
$opt1="";
$opt2="";
$opt3="";
$opt4="";
$answer="";
$count=0;
$ans="";


$queno=$_GET["questionno"];

if(isset($_SESSION["answer"][$queno]))
{
    $ans=$_SESSION["answer"][$queno];
}

$res=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from questions where category='$_SESSION[exam_category]' AND question_no=$_GET[questionno]");

$count=mysqli_num_rows($res);

if($count==0)
{
    echo "over";
}
else
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
            $question_no=$row["question_no"];
            $question=$row["question"];
            $opt1=$row["opt1"];
            $opt2=$row["opt2"];
            $opt3=$row["opt3"];
            $opt4=$row["opt4"];
    }
    ?>
    <br>

<table>
<h2><?php echo " ( ". $question_no ." ) ". $question; ?></h2>
<table>
<tr>
<input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="<?php echo $opt1; ?>" onclick="radioclick(this.value,<?php echo $question_no; ?>)" 
<?php
if($ans==$opt1){
    echo "checked";
}
?>>
<?php

if(strpos($opt1,'image/')!=false)
{
    ?>
<img src="admin/<?php echo $opt1?>" height="30" width="30">
    <?php
}
else
{
    echo $opt1;
}
?>
</tr>
<br>

<input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="<?php echo $opt2; ?>" onclick="radioclick(this.value,<?php echo $question_no; ?>)" 
<?php
if($ans==$opt2){
    echo "checked";
}
?>>
<?php

if(strpos($opt2,'image/')!=false)
{
    ?>
<img src="admin/<?php echo $opt2?>" height="30" width="30">
    <?php
}
else
{
    echo $opt2;
}
?>
</tr>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="<?php echo $opt3; ?>" onclick="radioclick(this.value,<?php echo $question_no; ?>)" 
<?php
if($ans==$opt3){
    echo "checked";
}
?>>
<?php

if(strpos($opt3,'image/')!=false)
{
    ?>
<img src="admin/<?php echo $opt3?>" height="30" width="30">
    <?php
}
else
{
    echo $opt3;
}
?>
</tr>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="<?php echo $opt4; ?>" onclick="radioclick(this.value,<?php echo $question_no; ?>)" 
<?php
if($ans==$opt4){
    echo "checked";
}
?>>
<?php

if(strpos($opt4,'image/')!=false)
{
    ?>
<img src="admin/<?php echo $opt4?>" height="30" width="30">
    <?php
}
else
{
    echo $opt4;
}
?>
</tr>
<br>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Wherever you learned this from, you must unlearn it. Please never write SQL queries like this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the response from php file `echo "over";` is a simple string as output to ajax so `if(xmlhttp.responseText=="over")` will not work there.

**Solution 1 :-**

Use `===` so `if(xmlhttp.responseText==='over')` might work.

**Solution 2 :-**

echo out integer as some success code to ajax.

for eg:-

```
if($count==0)
{
    echo "1";
}
```

then `if(xmlhttp.responseText == 1)`

**Solution 3:-**

Send Json encoded response from php and parse it at ajax side.

```
if($count==0)
{
   $res = array("status" => "over");
   echo json_encode($res);
}
```

then

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var res = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            if (res.status == "over"){
                 window.location="final.php";

        }
        else{
        document.getElementById("load_questions").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        load_total_que();
        }
}
```

For any queries comment down.

Comment: @MohmammedKhurram  Thanks it worked , I another question related to this can I ask?

Comment: Yaah sure, If this helped you may consider accepting it :), I will try to help @rishabhraj

Comment: I have edited the question please read  and help me

Comment: I Have seen this question somewhere before, wherever you got this from, you should try analyzing it and learn it thoroughly, then only you can figure out solutions for any problem.

Comment: That was  my question  only,  I am asking from everyone but no one helped, so I am asking from you,  see name is same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69136672/quiz-question-number-navigation-not-working-properly-ajax

Comment: Please help me sir

Comment: I have diplayed question  number but facing issue in getting  same question. Please  see the question.php

Comment: please  guide bhaiya

Comment: Try debugging that `question.php`, see what you are getting out of query, and without actual watching at the database it's hard to answer.

Comment: @MohhmmedKhurram  Suppose These are my question number navigation [ 1 ]  [ 2 ]  [ 3 ]  [ 4 ]  [ 5 ] , I have answered question number [1] and  when I  skipped question number [2] (directly clicked on question number [3] ) and I have clicked on next button to get question 4 , Problem is the question  [2] which I have skipped display whereas question number 4 should display. Are getting my qquestion or shall I host those scripts on infinityfree so that you will easily understand . Please guide bhaiya.